# When can every set in a monotone class $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{C})$ be written as a countable monotone union or intersection of sets in $\mathcal{C}$?

Tags: measure-theory

Under what conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ does it follow that the monotone class $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{C})$ generated by $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies the property that each $A \in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{C})$ can be written as the countable monotone union or intersection of sets in $\mathcal{C}$? Under what conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ does the same property hold for $\mathcal{M}(\sigma(\mathcal{C}))$?

If $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under countable unions and intersections, then this property seems to hold. Define
$$\mathcal{M}_0 = \{A : \text{there exists a sequence}\ \{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty} \in  \mathcal{C}\ \text{such that}\ A_i \uparrow A\ \text{or}\ A_i \downarrow A.\}$$
Clearly $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{M}_0$. If $\mathcal{M}_0$ can be shown to be a monotone class, then $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{C}) \subset \mathcal{M}_0$. Suppose $A_1, A_2, \cdots$ is a sequence of sets in $\mathcal{M}_0$ and $A_i \uparrow A$. For each $A_i$ there exists a sequence $\{A_{i,j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ such that either $A_{i,j} \uparrow A_i$ or $A_{i,j} \downarrow A_i$ and $A_{i,j} \in \mathcal{C}$ for all $j$. Suppose that for all but finitely many $i$ (say, for all $i \geq N$), $A_{i,j} \downarrow A_i$. Define
$$B_j = \cup_{i=N}^{\infty} A_{i,j}.$$
Then $B_1 \supset B_2 \supset \cdots$, and $B_j \downarrow A$. By assumption $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under countable unions so each $B_j \in \mathcal{C}$. Otherwise, if $A_{i,j} \uparrow A_i$ for infinitely many $A_{i_1}, A_{i_2}, \cdots$, we have that $(B_j := \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{i_k,j}) \uparrow A$, and as before each $B_j \in \mathcal{C}$. The proof for $A_i \downarrow A$ is similar. Then $\mathcal{M}_0$ is a monotone class.

In any case, if $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra, the monotone class theorem implies that $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}) = \sigma(\mathcal{A})$, which implies that $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}) = \mathcal{M}(\sigma(\mathcal{A}))$. Since $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is closed under countable unions and intersections, the above proof (if correct) implies that $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$ satisfies the desired property.

Is there anything more I can say about this? I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Comment: If $\mathcal{C}$ is already closed under countable unions and intersections, then in particular it is closed under countable monotone unions and intersections, so it is already a monotone class.  Thus $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{C}) = \mathcal{C}$ and the claim is trivially true.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Likewise, $\mathcal{M}(\sigma(\mathcal{C})) = \sigma(\mathcal{C})$.

Comment: @NateEldredge wow I completely screwed that up, you're totally right.